# Button is being overlapped by something and not functioning properly

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I created a custom view that holds a datepicker and a submit button. as I create and call this view in a view controller, the button doesn't work immediately I have to play with the datepickers dial a few times before it works. I sense that I have messed up with my constraints somehow since I'm fairly new to it. Any help is appreciated.

**This is my custom view code**

```
func setupDatePicker() {
    datepicker = UIDatePicker()
    datepicker.minimumDate = Date()
    datepicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePicker(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    datepicker.setValue(Colors.starYellow, forKey: "textColor")
}

func setupButton(){
    submitButton = CustomButton()
    submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateSubmission(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}

func addingSubviews() {
    setupButton()
    addSubview(submitButton)
    bringSubviewToFront(submitButton)
    setupDatePicker()
    addSubview(datepicker)
}



func setupConstraints(){

    addingSubviews()
    //Custom View Constraints
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    backgroundColor = Colors.darkBackground
    layer.cornerRadius = 15

    //DatePicker Constraints
    datepicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    datepicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    datepicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    datepicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    datepicker.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


    // Button Constraints

    submitButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    submitButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datepicker.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    submitButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datepicker.trailingAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    submitButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    submitButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: datepicker.bottomAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true



}


override func didMoveToSuperview() {
   setupConstraints()
}


@objc func datePicker(sender: UIDatePicker){
    self.datepicked = sender.date
    print("Date selected: \(datepicked)")
}
```

**This is the function that isn't being called**

```
    @objc func dateSubmission(sender: CustomButton){
        sender.shake()
        let currentDate = Date()
        let interval = datepicked?.timeIntervalSince(currentDate)
        print(interval)
        let notifcation = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notifcation.title = notificationTitle ?? "title empty"
        notifcation.subtitle = "test"
        notifcation.body = "test2"
        notifcation.badge = 1

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "taskReminder", content: notifcation, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }


}
```

and this is how *I created my custom view* in my view controller in which i want to display the view.

```
var customView: CustomView!
 func createReminderView(indexPath: IndexPath){
    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]

    customView = CustomView()
    customView.notificationTitle = task.task
    view.addSubview(customView)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(customView)
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

**View Debugger:**
[image]

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your view hierarchy as seen on the debugger?

Comment: Check if anything is on top of the submit button. If there is something, you need to update your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I am damn sure if you set **clipsToBounds = true** you won't able to see the button. because you don't have enough height for your custom view

What I can see is the error in constraints

1) Custom View Height is 80, But Datepicker height is **50** and start from center of your custom View so it's y Position would be **15**

2) Submit button Height is 30 , also top from 35 From Date picker which has only 15 Pixel available at bottom (because of center Y)

Solution :

Your constraint should be

**DatePicker** =--> Leading (CustomView), Trailing (CustomView), Top(CustomView), Bottom(Submit Button)

**Custom Button** =--> Leading , Trailing , as per your requirements , Bottom(CustomView), Height(30)

Comment: Enlighten me on the corrections needed to be applied

Comment: I applied the changes, it has changed the way it looks and the button is separated from the date pickers but it hasn't fixed my problem. the button is still static and not calling the function.

Comment: @CharlesXavier Share screen shot for expected output. and How you are using CustomView ?, You need to create property at class level otherwise your button event never call because your custom view instance deallocated

Comment: I'm calling the function that creates the view in a UIContextualAction action

Comment: Thing is the button works when i play with the dial of the date picker a few times. I keep adjusting the values and then press the button till it works and prints what i need

Comment: Try to bring button to front. using bringSubview(toFront

Comment: I did so and implemented it in my addingsubviews functions still the same :/